# Error mapping stateless beans with Spring

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I have a Java EE application that runs on JBoss 6.4 EAP and uses Spring Security. Apparently all Maven dependencies are mapped. However, at the moment stateless beans are loaded, the following message appears:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autenticacaoBO': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ajg2/AutenticacaoBO -- service jboss.naming.context.java.app."ajg2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".ajg2.AutenticacaoBO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ajg2/AutenticacaoBO -- service jboss.naming.context.java.app."ajg2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".ajg2.AutenticacaoBO
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:104)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:197)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:245)
```

File spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">


    <jee:local-slsb id="autenticacaoBO" jndi-name="java:app/ajg2/AutenticacaoBO" business-interface="br.jus.ajg.bo.IAutenticacaoBO"/>

    <bean id="appInternetAuthenticationProvider" class="br.jus.ajg.seguranca.AppInternetAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="autenticacaoBO" ref="autenticacaoBO"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="appIntranetAuthenticationProvider" class="br.jus.ajg.seguranca.AppIntranetAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="autenticacaoBO" ref="autenticacaoBO"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

File AppInternetAuthenticationProvider.java:

```
package br.jus.ajg.seguranca;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import br.jus.ajg.bo.IAutenticacaoBO;
import br.jus.ajg.modelo.Profissional;
import br.jus.ajg.util.VerifyRecaptcha;

@Component
public class AppInternetAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider, Serializable {

    private IAutenticacaoBO autenticacaoBO;

    /**
     * Este set é usado para injeção do EJB
     */
    public void setAutenticacaoBO(IAutenticacaoBO autenticacaoBO) {
        this.autenticacaoBO = autenticacaoBO;
    }

    public AppInternetAuthenticationProvider() {

    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (!autenticacaoBO.isSistemaEmManutencao()) {

            AppWebAuthenticationDetails webAuthDetail = (AppWebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();

            String gRecaptchaResponse = webAuthDetail.getRecaptcha_response();
            boolean validouRecaptcha = false;
            try {
                validouRecaptcha = VerifyRecaptcha.verify(gRecaptchaResponse);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                new AuthenticationServiceException("Problema na validação do recaptcha", e);
            }

            if (validouRecaptcha) {
                String login = authentication.getName();
                String senha = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
                String infoNavegador = ((AppWebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails()).getHeaderRequest();

                Profissional p = autenticacaoBO.getProfissionalBO().autenticaProfissional(login, senha, infoNavegador);
                if (p != null) {
                    return autenticacaoBO.geraTokenProfissional(p, senha);
                } else {
                    throw new AuthenticationServiceException("CPF ou senha inválidos");
                }
            } else {
                throw new AuthenticationServiceException("O desafio reCAPTCHA foi respondido incorretamente!");
            }

        } else {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Sistema em manutenção. Tente mais tarde.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you checked JNDI tree in JBoss to make sure java:app/ajg2/AutenticacaoBO is available ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pavel. In fact, I forgot a tip sent by the original developer of this project. Just added project libs to the classpath tab of the 'Open laucnh configuration' JBoss option.

JBoss started without errors and app is running fine.